# NextJS fast refresh is not working after using official installer

Tags: next.js13

I've been wanting to learn Next.js for a while so I decided to give it a try. Following the instructions at their website I ran `npx create-next-app@latest` on my powershell and waited until the process finished, then cd'd into the folder and ran `npm run dev`. Once the server opened I went to edit `app/page.js` just as their README and the default HTML suggests but absolutely nothing updates in my browser. I've tried Chrome, Firefox and Edge with no luck at all.

I'm working on latest version of Windows 11, I haven't done any other changes to the project after installing it but just in case I'll share the initialization settings and pyproject below.

```
PS E:\Desktop\Dev> npx create-next-app@latest
√ What is your project named? ... nextjs_learn
√ Would you like to use TypeScript? ... No
√ Would you like to use ESLint? ... Yes
√ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? ... Yes
√ Would you like to use `src/` directory? ... No
√ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) ... Yes
√ Would you like to customize the default import alias? ... No
Creating a new Next.js app in E:\Desktop\Dev\nextjs_learn.
```

pyproject.toml

```json
{
  "name": "nextjs_learn",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "eslint": "8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "postcss": "8.4.29",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  }
}
```

[image: Folder Structure]

Am I doing something wrong? The documentation states that Fast Refresh is enabled by default but I seem to be unable to make it work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After checking some more issues I updated node.js from 18 to 20 and somehow it worked. Maybe my node.js installation was too busy or idk... anyways I managed to make it work so thank you!